# Generic Interface containing Generic methods requires same constraints?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics

I have the following interface defined.

IDbContext

```
public interface IDbContext<T> : IDisposable where T : class
{
    DbSet<T> Set<T>();
    int SaveChanges();
}
```

Which is indirectly implemented by TestContext, notice TestContext derives from System.Data.Entity.DbContext.

```
public class TestContext: DbContext,IDbContext<Foo>
{

}
```

Foo is some entity

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The complier throws the following errors:

> The type 'T' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter
>   'TEntity' in the generic type or method
>   'System.Data.Entity.DbSet'     TestContext.cs
>
> The type 'T' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter
>   'TEntity' in the generic type or method
>   'System.Data.Entity.DbSet'     IDbContext.cs
>
> The constraints for type parameter 'TEntity' of method
>   'System.Data.Entity.DbContext.Set()' must match the
>   constraints for type parameter 'T' of interface method
>   'Domain.Logic.Repositories.IDbContext.Set()'.
>   Consider using an explicit interface implementation instead.
>   EntityFramework.dll

When I add the constraint to the Generic method in the IDbContext interface the errors go away:

```
public interface IDbContext<T> : IDisposable where T : class
{
    DbSet<T> Set<T>() where T : class;
    int SaveChanges();
}
```

I'm confused as to why do I need to explicitly define the constraint on the method when it's defined at the class level?

---

**Update**
Based on the comments I realized the mistake I had made.

I totally overlooked the type param on DbContext.Set() method. A type parameter on a generic method is different from its classes/interfaces type param if any, therefore should be named different. In my case I had couple of issues: 1) I had generic interface with a generic typed method with the same param name. 2) The generic typed method itself was modeled after DbContext.Set(), which has its own constraints but those constraints weren't applied to the generic method itself.

I went with option 3 as provided in the answer below:

```
public interface IDbContext : IDisposable {
DbSet<T> Set<T>() where T : class
int SaveChanges();
```

}

HTH

Comment: Your interface causes a warning. If you looked at it, it would tell you exactly what is wrong. Next time, don't ignore warnings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the `<T>` in `Set<T>` in `DbSet<T> Set<T>()` *or* give `T` a different name in `Set<T>` and you should be fine. Otherwise, you're defining a `T` that is *different* from the `T` parameter in `IDbContext<T>`. That's why the compiler needs the second constraint, it think it's a different `T`. Thus you want one of the following two options. First:

```
public interface IDbContext<T> : IDisposable where T : class {
    DbSet<T> Set();
    int SaveChanges();
}
```

or

```
public interface IDbContext<T> : IDisposable where T : class {
    DbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>() where TEntity : class;
    int SaveChanges();
}
```

[Alternatively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17181449/generic-interface-containing-generic-methods-requires-same-constraints/17181490#comment24880283_17181490), remove the generic parameter from `IDbContext`:

```
public interface IDbContext : IDisposable {
    DbSet<T> Set<T>() where T : class
    int SaveChanges();
}
```

Based on your [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17181449/generic-interface-containing-generic-methods-requires-same-constraints/17181490#comment24880229_17181490), the latter seems more geared towards your needs.

Comment: He could make it `out T` as well.

Comment: @Romoku: I think it would be better to just avoid the redefinition of `T`. It would be confusing and difficult to maintain where you can have calls like `IDbContext<int>.Set<string>()` not to mention having two types `T` in the class implementations which are unrelated.

Comment: @Jason: I'm trying to define the contract based on this generic method: `System.Data.Entity.DbContext.Set<TEntity>()`, whose signature is: `public DbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>() where TEntity : class;`   Removing `T` makes it a different method.

Comment: @Romoku That wouldn't work, `DbSet<T>` can't even be covariant, since it's a class, not an interface.

Comment: @Karl Well, that method is generic because `DbContext` normally isn't limited to a single entity. So, the wrong part is most likely making your `IDbContext` generic.

Comment: @Karl: No, I think you have a bit of a misunderstanding of generic types and generic methods. A class or interface can be generic; they have generic type parameters: `class Foo<T>` and `interface Bar<T>`. A method can also be generic. If the method is defined in a generic class or interface, and uses any of the type parameters in the parameters or return type for the method, that method is generic using the same type parameters. For example `class Foo<T> { T M() { } }`. Alternatively, a method can define *its own* type parameters: `class Foo { U M<U>() { } }`.

Comment: @Karl: If you want to have a method return generically typed `DbSet<TEntity>` then you have *three* options: 1. `[class|interface] [I]DbContext<T> { DbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>() { } }` 2. `[class|interface] [I]DbContext<TEntity> { DbSet<TEntity> Set() { } }` 3. `[class|interface] [I]DbContext { DbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>() { } }`. Options 1. and 3. are basically the same, except that `[I]DbContext` is generic vs. not generic; the point in 1. and 3. is that `TEntity` has nothing to do with any type parameters on `[I]DbContext`. In 2., `TEntity` in `Set` is "inherited" from `[I]DbContext`.

Comment: @Karl: In your case, you've gone with option 1., except you've named the generic type parameter for `Set` to be `T` instead of `TEntity`. This is *not* the same `TEntity` as in the definition of `[I]DbContext`.

Comment: @svick: Found the thing I missed, `DbSet<TEntity>` has the constraint `where TEntity : class`. I think this answer is applicable, removed mine.

Comment: @Jason: Thanks for the explanation! I went with option 3. I have selected your answer and update my post with explanation for future reader.